# JSF APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES lifecycle not call during POST request process

Tags: jsf, javabeans, cdi

I create  JSF form with Jquery Diaolg. When I submit my form , the request doesn't invoke my bean method on first click but calls it at second click. I implement a PhaseListener to debug and found out that during first click only RESTORE_VIEW and RENDER_RESPONSE were called. My Question is what can cause this.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:forseti="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition >
        <div jsf:id="modal-wizard-edit" class="modal">
            <div id="user-profile-3" class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" style="width:800px;">
                    <div id="modal-content">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" jsf:id="personne-morale-edit-form" jsf:prependId="false">
                            <div class="modal-header no-padding">
                                <div class="table-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <span class="white">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    Results for "Latest Registered Domains
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tabbable" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-16">
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#edit-basic">
                                            <i class="green ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-125"></i>
                                            Etat civil/Identité
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>

                                <div class="tab-content profile-edit-tab-content">
                                    <div id="edit-basic" class="tab-pane in active">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="edit-raison-sociale">Raison sociale:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                                        <input id="edit-raison-sociale" type="text" jsf:value="#{personneMoraleBean.selectedPersonneMorale.raisonSociale}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>


                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="edit-ifu">IFU:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                                        <input id="edit-ifu" type="text" jsf:value="#{personneMoraleBean.selectedPersonneMorale.ifu}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="nature_juridique_edit">Nature juridique:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                                        <h:selectOneMenu class="chosen-select" id="nature_juridique_edit" value="#{personneMoraleBean.selectedPersonneMorale.natureJuridique}" p:data-placeholder="#{bundle.champNatureAffaireClassification}" required="true" >
                                                            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
                                                            <f:selectItems value="#{personneMoraleBean.listeNatureJuridiques}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.libelle}" />
                                                            <f:converter converterId="natureJuridiqueConverter" />
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <script src="../../resources/components/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="secteur_edit">Secteurs d'activités:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                                        <h:selectManyListbox class="multiselect" id="secteur_edit" value="#{personneMoraleBean.selectedPersonneMorale.secteurs}" p:data-placeholder="#{bundle.champNatureAffaireClassification}" p:multiple="" required="true" >
                                                            <f:selectItems value="#{personneMoraleBean.listeSecteurActivites}" var="item"
                                                                           itemLabel="#{item.libelle}" itemValue="#{item}"/>
                                                            <f:converter converterId="secteurActiviteConverter"/>
                                                        </h:selectManyListbox>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <script src="../../resources/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    $('#secteur_edit').multiselect({
                                                        enableFiltering: true,
                                                        buttonClass: 'btn btn-white btn-primary',
                                                        templates: {
                                                            button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>',
                                                            ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',
                                                            filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><input class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text"/></div></li>',
                                                            filterClearBtn: '<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-white btn-grey multiselect-clear-filter" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times-circle red2"></i></button></span>',
                                                            li: '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label></label></a></li>',
                                                            divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',
                                                            liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item group"><label class="multiselect-group"></label></li>'
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                                </script>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="telephone_edit">Telephone:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                                        <forseti:phoneNumber id="telephone_edit" value="#{personneMoraleBean.selectedPersonneMorale.telephone}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>


                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                <div class="clearfix col-sm-12 ">

                                    <button  type="submit" jsf:id="submit-morale-edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" jsf:action="#{personneMoraleBean.doEdit}">
                                        Block Button
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.span -->
            </div><!-- /.user-profile -->
        </div><!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function ajaxMonitoringFinishEdit(data) {
                if (data.status == "success") {
                    $('#modal-wizard-edit').modal('hide');
                }
            }
        </script>

    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

This is my form code source

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package forseti.controller.personne;

import forseti.ejb.NatureJuridiqueFacade;
import forseti.ejb.PersonneMoraleFacade;
import forseti.ejb.SecteurActiviteFacade;
import forseti.jpa.personne.NatureJuridique;
import forseti.jpa.personne.PersonneMorale;
import forseti.jpa.personne.SecteurActivite;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 *
 * @author Gildasdarex
 */
@Named(value = "personneMoraleBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonneMoraleBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of PersonneMoraleBean
     */
    @Inject
    private PersonneMoraleFacade personneMoraleFacade;
    @Inject
    private SecteurActiviteFacade secteurActiviteFacade;
    @Inject
    private NatureJuridiqueFacade natureJuridiqueFacade;

    private PersonneMorale newPersonneMorale;
    private PersonneMorale selectedPersonneMorale;
    private List<PersonneMorale> listePersonneMorales;
    private SecteurActivite selectedSecteurActivite;

    public PersonneMoraleBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        newPersonneMorale = new PersonneMorale();
        selectedPersonneMorale = new PersonneMorale();
    }

    public PersonneMorale getNewPersonneMorale() {
        return newPersonneMorale;
    }

    public void setNewPersonneMorale(PersonneMorale newPersonneMorale) {
        this.newPersonneMorale = newPersonneMorale;
    }

    public PersonneMorale getSelectedPersonneMorale() {
        return selectedPersonneMorale;
    }

    public void setSelectedPersonneMorale(PersonneMorale selectedPersonneMorale) {
        this.selectedPersonneMorale = selectedPersonneMorale;
    }

    public List<PersonneMorale> getListePersonneMorales() {
        listePersonneMorales = personneMoraleFacade.findAll();
        return listePersonneMorales;
    }

    public List<SecteurActivite> getListeSecteurActivites() {

        return secteurActiviteFacade.findAll();
    }

    public List<NatureJuridique> getListeNatureJuridiques() {
        return natureJuridiqueFacade.findAll();
    }

    public SecteurActivite getSelectedSecteurActivite() {
        return selectedSecteurActivite;
    }

    public void setSelectedSecteurActivite(SecteurActivite selectedSecteurActivite) {
        this.selectedSecteurActivite = selectedSecteurActivite;
    }

    public void doCreate() {
        newPersonneMorale.setId(newPersonneMorale.getIfu());
        personneMoraleFacade.create(newPersonneMorale);
        listePersonneMorales = personneMoraleFacade.findAll();
    }

    public void doDel() {
        personneMoraleFacade.remove(selectedPersonneMorale);
    }

    public void doEdit() {
        System.out.println("edit "+selectedPersonneMorale.getId());
        System.out.println("edit "+selectedPersonneMorale.getIfu());
        System.out.println(selectedPersonneMorale.getRaisonSociale());
        System.out.println(selectedPersonneMorale.getNatureJuridique());
        System.out.println(selectedPersonneMorale.getSecteurs().size());
        personneMoraleFacade.edit(selectedPersonneMorale);
    }

    public void doRemoveSecteur() {
        selectedPersonneMorale.getSecteurs().remove(selectedSecteurActivite);
        personneMoraleFacade.edit(selectedPersonneMorale);
        listePersonneMorales = personneMoraleFacade.findAll();
    }

    public void passItemMoraleSecteur(PersonneMorale personneMorale, SecteurActivite secteurActivite) {
        selectedPersonneMorale = personneMorale;
        selectedSecteurActivite = secteurActivite;
    }

    public void passItem(PersonneMorale item) {
        selectedPersonneMorale = item;
        System.out.println("getItem "+selectedPersonneMorale.getId());

    }

}
```

Comment: The code is not in [MCVE flavor](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) (it contains a lot of noise), so it's hard to nail down the cause by just glancing over the code. Please update the question accordingly. At least, the symptoms suggest that it's actually not a POST request. How exactly have you observed and confirmed that it's a POST request?

Comment: The problem is that when I submit my form, The APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase is not call during request lifecycle.What can cause this??

Comment: That it's not a POST request. Now, please answer the question in my previous comment. Better yet, fix the question to include a true MCVE.

Comment: In my server log , as result of my form submission the RESTORE_VIEW phase is called, and RENDER_RESPONSE. Other phase are missing

Comment: ok I will include a true MCVE for you